# "open" modify and "save as" files to and from javascript / flash / silverlight or java in a web browser, Without uploading to server?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, flash, google-chrome, upload

What is the best way to have a file 'browse' dialog pop up and a user 'uploads' a file that I can retrieve in Javascript without uploading the file to a server just to download it back to the client in Javascript?

I found Downloadify for letting users 'download' a javascript generated file without bouncing off a server: https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify
is there a way to 'uploadify' a file the user browses to and opens and get it into Javascript in a data:url or some form without bouncing it off the server 100% client-side?

The ability to "open" a file the user selects from their hard drive, edit it in javascript and "save as" back out to the user's hard drive without any server-side code?

I am making a back-office so it doesn't need to be cross-browser if it's sported in google chrome, ideally in Javascript/HTML5, but flash or silverlight could work too, hopefully not java.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight lets you do that with the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class.  I am currently working on a Silverlight project and I exclusively use Chrome so you shouldn't have any problems in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Flash has support for reading and writing local files:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/20/reading-and-writing-local-files-in-flash-player-10/

For sending data between Flash and JavaScript, you can use the ExternalInterface API:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: ... but if you don't need cross-browser support, only Google Chrome, then I guess you can use the HTML5 File API: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file